# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable in python 2.7.6

Tags: python, opencv

here is the part of code:

```
contours,hierarchy =  cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_CCOMP,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
found_Obj=False
if (hierarchy.size() > 0):
    numObj =hierarchy.size()
```

but I'm getting this error :

```
    if (hierarchy.size() > 0):
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: Isn't it clear from the error message that `hierarchy.size` is an integer? Use `if hierarchy.size > 0:` and `numObj = hierarchy.size` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According [Python OpenCV Contour tree hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11782147/python-opencv-contour-tree-hierarchy) the `hierarchy` object returned is a [`numpy.ndarray` object](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html). The [`numpy.ndarray.size` attribute](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.size.html#numpy.ndarray.size) is a simple integer, *not* a method, and your error message tells you this.

Remove the `()` calls:

```
if hierarchy.size > 0:
    numObj = hierarchy.size
```

or even:

```
if hierarchy.size:
    numObj = hierarchy.size
```

as the size is never going to be negative.