# How do I get the segmented regions from watershed (OpenCV - C++) for further classification

Tags: c++, opencv, contour, image-segmentation, watershed

I want to get all the segmented regions. I want to test if a particular segment is round (cell) or not.

Can I use findingcontour in this kind of problem?

[image: Segmented Image]

***Edit

I've successfully get the segmented regions using contours. Any suggestion on how to classify these contour depending on their shape. (Remove the non-circular contours).

The situation looks like these :

[image: Segmented Regions]

Comment: Just try it out, and you'll see! Also, please consider [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and have a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions around here. In general, provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your _specific_ problem.

Comment: Okay2x, I'll try it out. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should work for you. If "wshed" will be your input image for the `findContours()` function.
If you think that it is possible that there will be nested regions, you should use `CV_RETR_TREE` if you want to process them in a special way, `CV_RETR_LIST` if you want to handle the regions in a region too or `CV_RETR_EXTERNAL` if you want to ignore all nested regions.
See [Doc](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours) and an [Example](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4.13.7/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html) for usage.

EDIT 1.0:

To answer your edit: circular contours will have one outer and one inner contour. So if you use `CV_RETR_TREE` and check for each contour if there is another contour inside, it is a circular contur and you can keep it and delete all other contours. See [here under 4. RETR_TREE](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d8b/tutorial_py_contours_hierarchy.html) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11782147/python-opencv-contour-tree-hierarchy) for usage

EDIT 2.0:
Seems I missunderstood you. With "circular" in Edit 1.0 i meant closed objects. Now I am not shure what you mean with circular. If convexity is sufficient i would lead you to [`convecHull`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#convexhull) and [`convexityDefects`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#convexitydefects).

If you it is realy necessary to have a circle/oval shape, i would try to calculate the parameters of the oval or circle based on the contour and to draw an ideal circle/oval based on these and compare the contour with it. But maybe there are better ways to to that. In that case i would recommend you to ask it as a new question, because it does not has anythin to do with the topic of this question.