# Form based segmentation

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation

Is there a segmentation algorithm that is not based on pixel intensity but rather **form** of the resulting shapes? Imagine a grayscale image where simpler forms like Ellipses and curved lines are superimposed. Is there a segmentation approach that splits connected components repeatedly until "simpler" forms are obtained? I illustrate this in the attached image

[image: 1]

Comment: for *that*? filter banks maybe. or AI. -- "segmentation" refers to per-pixel labeling (boolean/integer labels) of images. pixels are a reasonable representation of a shape. you instead drew red lines "separating" various parts of your shape. if you mean to use another representation of your shape, then you should be a bit more explicit in that. it affects the meaning of "segmentation"

Answer (score 0):

> Sometimes objects / shapes are in different locations. But in some
> cases, some shapes are inside other shapes (what you call
> superimposed), just like nested figures.

In this case, we call the outer one as parent and inner one as child. This way, contours in an image has some relationship to each other. And we can specify how one contour is connected to each other, like, is it a child of some other contour, or is it a parent, etc. Representation of this relationship is called **[the Hierarchy](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d8b/tutorial_py_contours_hierarchy.html)**.

You can use this hierarchy to analyze or to obtain simpler forms (children) of your initial complex shape or form (parent).

**Contours** : Contours can be explained simply as a curve joining all the continuous points (along the boundary), having same color or intensity. The contours are a useful tool for shape analysis and object detection and recognition.

In Open CV this is implemented within: [cv2.findContours()](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html)

As also briefly touched in the comments, how you define "objectiveness" or "represenatation of shape" need to be specified by you beforehand during your segmentation approach which defines the above mentioned boundary. The simplest approach to that is then e.g. a thresholding.

Example image: [image]

From the stackoverflow thread I recommended here: [Python OpenCV Contour Tree Hierarchy Structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11782147/python-opencv-contour-tree-hierarchy-structure)

Comment: + maybe also a nice question thread to read through: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11782147/python-opencv-contour-tree-hierarchy-structure

Comment: No I don't mean simply shapes within a shape. I  mean that shapes like lines and ellipses cross each other and touch like illustrated in the image. Contours is unusable in this case because everything would be one big contour. I would imagine these contours to be a starting point that have some metric that describe shape complexity. The contour would then have to be split repeatedly to arrive at simpler shapes like lines and ellipses (until the complexity metric reaches a threshold). I guess there is no simple solution to this.

Comment: Yes, exactly what contours does. It splits into multiple simpler shapes. I added an image from the stackoverflow thread I posted above in a comment. And then as said, the shape description needs to be done during the specification of your segmentation approach. When these shapes cross and touch each other, it does only mean that there is a hull or in other words contour around them and they again will be inside that shape. It is a thing to wrap your head around, I agree.

Comment: that is exactly *not* what `findContours` does. it delineates connected components. it does not split those by shape.

Comment: Oh, it looks like I made a friend. Define components and shapes. As said in my comment before: "And then as said, the shape description needs to be done during the specification of your segmentation approach." - and I think I made clear that you need to add a "representation of shape" yourself and that findcontours does not do that for you. Looking forward to your contribution to this, I might learn something.